# How do I get Homebrew to recognize my Git install?

Tags: terminal, homebrew

I've installed [Homebrew](http://mxcl.github.io/homebrew/) and fixed all of the errors that brew doctor reports, except this one:

```
martinjames$ brew doctor
Warning: An outdated version of Git was detected in your PATH.
Git 1.7.10 or newer is required to perform checkouts over HTTPS from GitHub.
Please upgrade: brew upgrade git
```

I take homebrew's advice:

```
martinjames$ brew upgrade git
Error: git not installed
```

So, I check for git:

```
martinjames$ which git
/usr/bin/git
```

And I check for the version:

```
martinjames$ git --version
git version 1.7.5.4
```

What's next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the answer involved two things. First, I needed to do this:

```
brew update
```

And then this:

```
brew install git
```

The brew doctor command reported a problem with my path, so I ended up creating a .bash_profile in my home directory to make sure /usr/local/bin came before /usr/bin.

Now I'm ready to brew!